# Which relation type to choose when having array of ids as part of the document

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

Every order has productIds property which is an array of productIds as explained bellow.
How should I implement the relations in StrongLoop \ Loopbck 3?

I couldn't find in the [document](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-model-relations.html) the right relation type i should choose.
I'm using MongoDB.

```
Orders

{
  "_id": "5bc9eed3336746028d88651f",
  "name": "My Order",  
  "createdAt": "2018-10-19T14:48:50.961Z",
  "updatedAt": "2018-11-21T09:57:34.729Z",
  "currency": "EUR",  
  "productIds": ["5f16de532b3fa13644bdf513", "5f170559afcb6d3644ee4f1e"]
}

Products
{
  "_id": "5f16de532b3fa13644bdf513",
  "name": "Product One",  
  "createdAt": "2018-10-19T14:48:50.961Z",
  "updatedAt": "2018-11-21T09:57:34.729Z"
}

{
  "_id": "5f170559afcb6d3644ee4f1e",
  "name": "Product Two",  
  "createdAt": "2018-10-19T14:48:50.961Z",
  "updatedAt": "2018-11-21T09:57:34.729Z"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on whether you need to reference back from the product to the corresponding orders.

**Case 1:**
If you need that and the products can be related to many orders, the right relation is ManyToMany. For lb3 and this type of relation you can use the [hasAndBelongsToMany relation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/HasAndBelongsToMany-relations.html).

**Case 2:**
If you need that and each product can be related to one order then use the hasMany relation.

**Case 3:**
If you don't need that, then the best choice would be the [referencesMany](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Embedded-models-and-relations.html), as it allows to connect the orders to their corresponding products without affecting the product instances.

From your description, I would guess that the case 3 matches what you are trying to build, so I would go with the **referencesMany**.

Example Definition:

```js
{
  "name": "Order",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "name": "string"
  },
  "relations": {
    "products": {
      "type": "referencesMany",
      "model": "Product",
      "foreignKey": "productIds"
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Could you please kindly show how can i implement choice 3 but with the structure i mentioned as only the productid are part of the products array in the order?

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear so you can follow it without problems, but I'll edit the answer to add the definition